# Searching for an item of an arraylist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my JS file externally linked to my HTML document. What i am trying to achieve is typing a letter(s) of one of the array properties name in an input search from html form, then when i submit the form the matching names in the arraylist is suppose to popup in the div with an id of output. But it doesnt work. Need some help on this please.

```
/* Address Book Data, this is our JSON object*/
var contacts = {
"addressBook" : [//The groupingPropertyBracket
{//The objectPropertyBracket
    "name": "hillisha",
    "email": "hill@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "paul",
    "email": "cleveland@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "vishal",
    "email": "vishal@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "mike",
    "email": "grady@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "jamie",
    "email": "dusted@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Shantal",
    "email": "mygirlfriend@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Vern",
    "email": "mybro@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Tose",
    "email": "mysecondbro@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Mehdy",
    "email": "mylittlebro@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Mummy",
    "email": "myMother@example.com",
},
{
    "name": "Travis",
    "email": "mypadner@example.com",
}//The objectPropertyBracket
]//The groupingPropertyBracket
};
//Adding a Listener to a Form submit Event

/*define the adr object to hold your methods (aka functions) */
var adr = {
//define the form submit event method
search : function(event){
    //prevent the default bahavior
    event.preventDefault();

    //save the DOM element we're putting the output in
    var target = document.getElementById("output");

    //save the contacts JSON object to a variable
    var book = contacts.addressBook;

    /* save the length to a variable outside the loop for performance */
    var count = book.length;
    var searchValue = document.getElementById('q');
    var i;
    target.innerHTML = "";

    //check the count, ofcourse and check to see if the value isn't empty
    if(count > 0 && searchValue !== ""){            //loop through the contacts

        for(i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1) {
            //look through the name value to see if
            //it contains the searchterm string
            var obj = contacts.addressBook[i];
            isItFound = obj.name.indexOf(searchValue);

            //anything other than -1 means we found a match
            if(isItFound !== -1) {
            target.innerHTML += '<p>' + obj.name + ', <a href="mailto:' + obj.email +      '">'+ obj.email +'</a></p>';             
            }// end if
        }//end for loop
    } // end count check
}//end method
}//end object

//save the button to a variable
var btn = document.getElementById("getall"),//click
searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");//this links to the form in HTML


searchForm.addEventListener("submit", adr.search, false);
```

and my HTML FORM:

```
<form action="" method="get" id="search-form">

        <div class="section">
            <label for="q">Search address book</label>
            <input type="search" id="q" name="q" required placeholder="type a name">
        </div> 

        <div class="button-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btn-search"> Search</button>
            <button type="button" id="getall"> Get all contacts</button>
        </div> 

    </form>
    <div id="output"></div> <!-- /#output -->
```

Comment: `it doesnt work` is not a proper problem statement to use for others to help troubleshooting. You might as well say `here's my code, fix it`

Comment: Have you looked at your browsers Javascript console?  Are there error messages?

Comment: It looks like you are using `indexOf` on the `.name` option of your array; in a way that you can't do.  You need to use a for-loop and check the `.name` values with the type of structure you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code ... this should get an answer.

Try ...

```
var searchValue = document.getElementById('q').value;
```

... you need the `.value` of the element; also you aren't looking at an array, but an object in the array, so ...

```
var obj = contacts.addressBook[i];
isItFound = -1;
if (obj.name===searchValue) {
  isItFound = i;
}
```

I used the odd `isItFound = -1` to compensate for the rest of the code written to allow for `indexOf` ...

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/a7ynspmr/)**